# LINQ query with multiple joins and contains is not working

Tags: c#, linq

I have an existing LINQ query that has been functioning correctly:

```
public partial class UserFacilityAccess
{
    public int UserFacilityAccessId {get; set;}
    public int FacilityId {get; set;}
    public Guid AppUserId {get; set;}
}

appUsers = (from a in _context.AppUsers
           join uf in _context.UserFacilityAccesses on new { p1 = a.AppUserId, p2 = FacilityID } equals new { p1 = uf.AppUserId, p2 = uf.FacilityId }
           into jn
           from c in jn.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where c.UserFacilityAccessId == null 
           select a)
           .OrderBy(o => o.AppUserDisplayName).ToList();
```

Now I have an additional requirement, to check against a list of FacilityIds.  What I've done is the following:

```
List<int> facilities = (from f in _context.Facilities
                       join c in _context.Clients on f.ClientID equals c.ID
                       join g in _context.Groups on c.GroupID equals g.ID
                       where ((GroupID == 0 || g.ID == GroupID) && (ClientID == 0 || c.ID == ClientID))
                       select f.ID).ToList();
```

That list populates successfully containing all the valid facility IDs.  I tried the following modification to my original query and it now returns no rows at all regardless of settings, so clearly I'm doing something wrong.  I could join the created facilities to UserFacilityAccesses table but I'm not sure how to do that.  I want to restrict UserFacilityAccesses to records with FacilityId in the list of facilities that I've created.  Here's what I attempted:

```
appUsers = (from a in _context.AppUsers
           join uf in _context.UserFacilityAccesses on new { p1 = a.AppUserId, p2 = FacilityID } equals new { p1 = uf.AppUserId, p2 = uf.FacilityId }
           into jn
           from c in jn.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where c.UserFacilityAccessId == null && facilities.Contains(c.FacilityId)
           select a)
           .OrderBy(o => o.AppUserDisplayName).ToList();
```

This runs without error but returns no rows so apparently the Contains clause is not working properly.  I'm stumped as to how to get this to work.  As an experiment, I tried changing that contains clause to instead hard-code an ID that I know would be returned by the UserFacilityAccesses table and just added c.FacilityId == 5 and that returns nothing either.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your code have a warning like this: *"The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'"*?

Comment: may be you are looking for `where c == null || facilities.Contains(c.FacilityId)` or `where c != null && facilities.Contains(c.FacilityId)`

Comment: In first query it looks like you are using wrong tables from context (you don't tell us what are `_context.Clients` and `_context.Groups` ). In second query I see two problems:     1) `c.UserFacilityAccessId == null` and property is not nullable (mentioned in answers)

Comment: 2) `into jn from c in jn.DefaultIfEmpty()` 
when you have `join ... into` this is group join. After that `DefaultIfEmpty()` is not logical to me. If you want `LEFT JOIN` you can just use this syntax:
`from uf in _context.UserFacilityAccesses.Where(x => x.AppUserId == a.AppUserId && x.FacilityID == a.FacilityID ).DefaultIfEmpty`

Comment: You can after that check if `uf == null` but then what is the point of `LEFT JOIN`? Maybe you just need `join ... ` and then `where facilities.Contains(uf.FacilityId)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your queries are using anti-join (left outer join excluding the records which match the join criteria), but the the former is correctly applying the right side filter *before* the join, and the later is trying to apply it *after* the join, where it is too late, since it is already filtered to contain to records.

Here is what I mean. In first query

```
join uf in _context.UserFacilityAccesses
on new { p1 = a.AppUserId, p2 = FacilityID }
equals new { p1 = uf.AppUserId, p2 = uf.FacilityId }
into jn from c in jn.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

`FacilityId` condition is hidden inside the join criteria (`p2` of the keys). The above is is equivalent of

(1)

```
join uf in _context.UserFacilityAccesses
    .Where(x => FacilityId == x.FacilityID) // <-- pre filter
on a.AppUserId equals uf.AppUserId // <-- inner join
into jn from c in jn.DefaultIfEmpty() // <-- convert the inner join to left outer join
```

or even better understandable sub query syntax

(2)

```
from c in _context.UserFacilityAccesses
    .Where(x => FacilityId == x.FacilityID
        && a.AppUserId == x.AppUserId)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
where c == null
```

or even better (to not confuse with anti-join and the what is null and where to apply the filter), the normal condition for "not having matching record"

(3)

```
where !_context.UserFacilityAccesses
    .Any(x => FacilityId == x.FacilityID
        && a.AppUserId == x.AppUserId)
```

and the best is to use navigation property (`_context` variable indicates that you are using EF6 or EF Core)

(4)

```
where !a.UserFacilityAccesses
    .Any(x => FacilityId == x.FacilityID)
```

All these (including the original) are equivalent and differ only by the readability. But the last 4 syntaxes allow you to easily change the `FacilityId` condition which is not possible with the original syntax and led you to improper place/bug.

With all that being said, the solution of the problem in question is to pick any of those 4 queries and simply replace

```
FacilityId == x.FacilityID
```

with

```
facilities.Contains(x.FacilityID)
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to say in my comments, but more detailed.

Comment: Thanks!  that did the trick!  appreciate the help

Answer (score -1):

int cannot be null in comparison.

```
      public partial class UserFacilityAccess
      {
       public int UserFacilityAccessId {get; set;}
       public int FacilityId {get; set;}
       public Guid AppUserId {get; set;}
      }
```